# Meaning: To This Day

Tags: time

I have a question about the phrase "to this day": (from Frederick the Great by Giles MacDonogh)

> [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=-YATAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=%22they+still+crop+up+to+this+day%22&source=bl&ots=4N0rKfqSsP&sig=hDltevXh0LkSyQDsRSiMmmsgFlg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qiAIVI64JMPHiwLRjIHQBw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22they%20still%20crop%20up%20to%20this%20day%22&f=false)
>   They started appearing even before his death on 17 August 1786, and they still crop up ***to this day***.

Should "*to this day*" be read in the sense of "to a point in time" ("he worked from 1 pm to midnight") or "at a point in time" ("at this moment")?

Answer (score 1):

"To this day" is an unusual phrasing, only used to talk about something that has been going on a long time and is still that way.  It would not be used for short time periods or indicating the turn-over of a calendar day in the minute past midnight.  You should generally think of not using it for anything much less than a year; and usually much longer spans of time.

For instance, a difficult problem known to the ancient Greeks might turn out to be *"still unsolved, to this day."*  And to put stronger and more mysterious emphasis on how odd it is that no one has figured it out, you might phrase it as *"still unsolved, **even** to this **very** day"*.

Going for something less dramatic, the casual "until today" doesn't specify a clock time.  If I said *"I didn't know that until today"*, I am not suggesting I got an email about it at midnight.  I am saying *"I didn't know this fact prior to the current calendar day, and only found out at a clock time prior to us speaking now."*

*(Note: We sometimes consider a very late hour like 1:00 AM to be the previous day's "night".  Hence I might say "I saw them yesterday night" on Monday, even if I had actually seen them earlier on that same Monday at 1:00 AM.)*

To get more specific about "day" you have to modify it.  There are phrases like *"You will receive it by the next **business day**"* which means that if someone says that on a Friday, you will not get it until Monday (assuming Monday is not a work holiday).  *"The next day, she opened the letter"* or similar phrases are ambiguous about time.

You will have to be specific if a specific time is meant.  For instance: *"As the clock struck midnight, the phantom appeared."*

That is all very far from the understanding when people would use *"to this day"*.  Once again, it is only a rare phrasing used to indicate a long time frame extending all the way up to the present...usually for dramatic and/or mysterious effect.

Comment: Could it be that "they still crop up ***to this day***" = "they still crop up ***even now***"?

Comment: They are close, but I try to point out the nuance in usage.  And "to this day" really is reserved for long periods of time, while "even now" you could interchangeably use for events in a short period.  *"I gave an answer.  I edited my answer to be clearer.  Yet even now, after I've additionally clarified with a comment, @meatie doesn't get the nuance!"*  Just kidding.  :-)  But if that were the situation, that would be a case where one would not use "to this day" as equivalent.

Comment: I agree with a lot of what you wrote, but I feel I should point out that [*to this day* is not actually an unusual phrase](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=32818308).

Comment: @snailplane It's an unusual *phrasing*.  I don't mean to say it's a [statistically improbable phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistically_Improbable_Phrases), just that it's not a terribly regular language construct that follows rules that are easy to understand without some native speaker hammering it out for you.

Comment: @snailplane If you prefer, read as "curious phrasing"; if it was rarely used, I'd have said "rarely used" or "archaic" or something like that.  Although: even if it is common in textual corpus I would say that it is uncommon in daily speech...more likely to appear in movies or television trying to be dramatic.

Comment: By the way, COCA is not strictly a corpus of written English.  One fifth of the corpus (80 million words) is [the SPOKEN subcorpus of unscripted conversation (from TV and radio transcripts)](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/help/spoken_e.asp), and interestingly [the phrase is most frequent in that subcorpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=32820843).  I agree it makes things more dramatic.

Comment: I don't see anything *unusual* about the phrase "(even) to this day". I think your post would be much better if you merely deleted ***"an unusual phrasing, only"*** from it. imo.

Answer (score 0):

**this day** refers to today (actually it would be the day this was written).
The meaning would be like:

> ... and they still crop up at times **between then and now**.

Comment: Could it be that "they still crop up ***to this day***" = "they still crop up ***even now***"?

Comment: @meatie Sounds OK to me.